# How to use IN with xmlreader

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, linq, xmlreader

How to use `IN(,,,)` with `xmlreader` to get specific nodes.

```
private static IEnumerable<DayNode> ReadDayNodes(string filePath)
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
            using (XmlReader xrdr = new XmlTextReader(fs))
                while (xrdr.Read())
                    if (xrdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xrdr.LocalName == "day")
                        yield return new DayNode(xrdr.GetAttribute("name"), xrdr.GetAttribute("short"), xrdr.GetAttribute("day"));
        }
```

If i have list of string.
like this :

`List<string> names = new new List<string>();`

and i wanna to get only the nodes which `name` in the previous list .How to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean, where the element's local-name isn't necessary "day", but rather is in the list?

```
if(xrdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && names.Contains(xrdr.LocalName))
```

Edit following on comments:

```
if (xrdr.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element && xrdr.LocalName == "day")
  foreach(string localName in names)
  {
    string attVal = xrdr.GetAttribute(localName);
    if(attVal != null)
    //we could just yield return attVal, but presuming we want to know which attribute it was on:
     yield return Tuple.Create(localName, attVal);
  }
```

Comment: no , i mean where `xrdr.GetAttribute("name")` value in the given list

Comment: How is the DayNode constructor to know which string is which?

Comment: hmmm, i don't know , i ask if there's some way to get the nodes which values are in specific list .

Comment: this means , i will get all the nodes , and filter the result later ?

Comment: Have added something that returns tuples of the names and values, though it may be less useful than what you had in your original question!